# Execute parent method in inherited classes

Tags: python, inheritance

I have an abstract class `Reader` that defines a `reader` method that will implement each of the inherited classes. What I want to do is execute the `_is_valid` method at the beginning of each implementation of the `reader` method but I don't want to have to repeat the code in each of the classes or use decorators.

```
import os

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

import pandas as pd


class Reader(ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def read(cls, f):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @staticmethod
    def _valid(f):
        return os.path.exists(f)


class CSVReader(Reader):
    def read(self, f):
        if not self._valid(f):
            return None
        else:
            return pd.read_csv(f).values


class XLSReader(Reader):
    def read(self, f):
        pass


class SHPReader(Reader):
    def read(self, f):
        pass
```

Any idea what is the best way to solve it?

Comment: In the parent class' `read` method, add a call to the `_valid` method and remove the `raise NotImplemented`
In your subclasses you'll have to add something like `super().read(f)`. I'm sure you don't want to use descriptors?

Comment: How is that better than using decorators that execute the validation? What I'm trying to avoid is having to repeat that line of code in the other classes (not many, but being formats could be thousands (JPG, PNG, DOC, TXT, etc.) Is that the pythonic way to do it? (Likewise, I really like what you propose)

Comment: A decorator would require being added in each concrete subclass. Since you want to guarantee that each subclass does this, adding it in the base class is the way to go - that's what inheritance is there for. In Python, it is absolutely fine for an ABC to be *partially* concrete. The builtin ABCs, such as Set, Mapping and the like, do the same.

Comment: That's a nice explanation. But I still need to add `super().read(f)` in each subclass, right? Repeating that line bothers me a lot, but if it's the way to do it in Python, that's how it will be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Reader` class could have a public method `read` that it defines that calls `_valid` then `_read`

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Reader(ABC):  # Or metaclass=ABCMeta
    def read(self, f):
        if not self._valid(f):
            raise ValueError("Invalid")
        else:
            return self._read(f)
    @abstractmethod
    def _read(self, f)
        raise NotImplementedError
    @classmethod
    def _valid(cls, f)  # Subclasses can have more restrictive validations
        return os.path.exists(f)
```

Comment: This is interesting. What I should do then is to implement the `_read` method in each of the subclasses?

Comment: @nikolat328 Yes.  You can also define `_valid` methods of those subclasses, and `read` will pick up those methods.

Comment: Excellent! I do not know if it's a good practice to override private methods (is it?), but it's the best solution I saw. Thank you!

Comment: @nikolat328 What you'd probably do is write a method that calls `super()._valid(f)`, then performs some validations of its own.  I wouldn't worry too much about the public/private distinction when writing Python classes, just when using them.  There's also no real pressing reason for `_valid` to be private in the first place.